# Born Approximation at Low Energies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

According to Griffiths, in a typical scattering scenario, we have $$\psi(r, \theta) = A\left(e^{ikz} + f(\theta, \phi) \frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\right)$$ Where $k = \frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}$.
I.e an incident plane wave, and a scattered spherical wave (at large distances from the scattering centre, where the scattering potential is negligible). It can be derived, after making the Born Approximation, that $$f(\theta, \phi) = -\frac{m}{2 \pi \hbar^2} \int e^{i (\textbf{k -}' \textbf{k}) 
 \cdot \textbf{r}'} V(\textbf{r}') d^3 \textbf{r}' $$

Where $\textbf{k} = k \hat{r}$, $\textbf{k}' = k \hat{z}$.

And then in the limit that $E \ \text{(Energy)} \to 0$,

$$f(\theta, \phi) = -\frac{m}{2 \pi \hbar} \int V(\textbf{r}) d^3 \textbf{r}$$

The reasoning behind this step in the book is

> The exponential term is essentially constant over the scattering region.

I do not understand this reasoning, nor can I find any justification for this step. Some further explanation would be appreciated.

This is from Griffiths' Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, Second Edition, p.417.

Comment: Both k-vectors have the same magnitude k, the magnitude of the momentum is $\hbar k$, the kinetic energy is $\hbar^2 k^2/(2m)$. So,  in the low energy limit $k$ goes to zero, and the exponential becomes constant over the region where the potential does not vanish.

Comment: Thank you, it seems so obvious now... Should the post be kept up?